# Sorting vertices by Minimum Spanning Trees in a forest of MSTs

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a number of vertices. They are separated into a number of Minimum Spanning Trees (MSTs) (so there's a forest of MSTs) using Kruskal's algorithm. For each vertex I need to know in which MST they are located. Each MST will be assigned a unique ID.

When completed I will know, for example, that Vertex #12 is in MST #2.

This is my best attempt at this. As you can see the algorithm failed because it falsely tagged one MST as two separate MSTs (Blue Group 0 and Blue Group 1):

[image]

I'm looking for an algorithm that can do this. Thanks in advance. I'm a programmer not a mathematician.

To answer questions from comments:

1. MST = Minimum Spanning Tree
2. I don't know in advance how many MSTs I'll end up with.
3. Basically, I'm confronted with the forest of MSTs and then I have to count them and tag the vertices.

Comment: Why wouldn't you state what an *MST* is in order to get more help?  It looks like classic *nearest-neighbor clustering* but it is hard to know because you didn't explain what *MST* means.  Can you post your data?

Comment: Morgan, no the MSTs are correct. It's the tagging that's off. The last step of Kruskal's algorithm DID NOT join the trees in question. It should be one big MST.

Comment: @zetar:  "It should be one big MST."  But of course it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can try nearest-neighbor clustering and adjust the criterion distance $d$: 
 [Nearest-neighbor clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_chain_algorithm):

[image]

Comment: My current algorithm worked on the fact that any 2 vertices closer than the threshold distance that Kruskal used to separate the MSTs must be in the same MST. HOWEVER, the algorithm failed when one MST (in the above picture) was so long that vertices in the same MST were 2 or 3 times further apart than the cutoff threshold. I think this is programming / logic error.